# K2 blackpearl multilingual application

Tags: internationalization, k2, k2-blackpearl

We are going to make an application in K2 blackpearl and it has to be translated into Spanish and Portuguese (Something similar to i18n in Java). We have been investigating and all we have found is a custom control that makes it possible. The code could be downloaded on this page:

http://community.k2.com/t5/K2-blackpearl/Multilingual/ba-p/1049

But unfortunately, and I do not know why, when I try to download it shows me a message indicating that it is no longer available.
Anyone know how translate our K2 blackpearl application to Spanish and Portuguese?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link seems to be working now. You need to be logged in.